# Change superclass arguments in subclass

Tags: python, inheritance

I am a bit confused on how I can change the superclass arguments in the subclass. Consider this example.

I have a class like this:

```
Class Bird(Animal):
    def __init__(self, color, arg2=Animal.x, ..., arg100=Animal.x100, **kwargs):
        self._arg_b1 = b1
        self.arg_b2 = b2

        super(Bird, self).__init(**args)
```

Now I want to create a subclass of this class, for example, Crow.

```
Class Crow(Bird):
   pass
```

I want for this Crow class to change the colour to black, so when we create the Crow class it does not need colour argument. But also I don't want to initialise all other arguments in my subclass since I don't need to change anything about them. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass the literal string `'black'` up to the superclass:

```py
class Bird(Animal):
    def __init__(self, color, **kwargs):
        self.color = color
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class Crow(Bird):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__('black', **kwargs)
```

then you can instantiate a `Bird` and `Crow` like this:

```py
b = Bird('white')
c = Crow()
print(f'Bird color:{b.color} Crow color:{c.color}')
```

Comment: Ideally, it should be passed as a keyword argument, both to play nicely with `super` and to override any use of `color` in `kwargs`: `kwargs['color'] = 'black'; super().__init__(**kwargs)`.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared some part of the problem for me. 

However, what happens to `arg2`? Do I need to give the same default value to it in the  `__init__` of my subclass?

Comment: I see you have `arg2=Animal.x`, but you don't show what happens to it.

Comment: for example, consider `arg2` is `scientific classification` of the animal. by default, every animal has "Animalia" (`Animal.x`) as value. We don't want to change that.

In the time of instantiation, one can specify a more detailed classification. I just want my new class to have the same default value for the classification. Should I give the default value to it again?

Comment: So, did you try it? What value does `c` (my Crow()) have for `arg2`? I can't tell. I don't know what happens to it in `Bird`

Comment: I was getting errors for not providing the required arguments. 

I changed the content of `__init__` to this: `super().__init__(**kwargs)` and also added this: `self.color = 'black'`. 

it seems to work fine now.